# How can I launch an Android via an http URL using any host extenstion?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Android intent filter which I use to launch an app when the user navigates to "http://www.foo.com/path".

I would now like to be able to launch the app from any host extention - e.g. "http://www.foo.co.uk/path".

I have tried a wildcard for the extension, but it doesn't work:

```
<data android:scheme="http"
android:host="www.foo.*"
android:pathPrefix="/play/mob" />
```

Comment: So you also want it to launch for `www.foo.realbadguys.com` or `www.foo.yourcompetitors.tv`?

Comment: No - just: www.foo.co.uk or www.foo.co.nz or www.foo.tv

Comment: So it's not "any host extension". You'll most likely have to list them individually to avoid issues.

Comment: AFAIK, `host` does not support wildcards, and there is no `hostPattern`. Your choices are either to handle all `http` URLs or to have `<data>` elements for each supported host.

Comment: I don't think android:host even accepts a regexp, only wildcards, but even if it did and you created a regexp that limits the length to what fits co.uk or co.nz, nothing stops it from matching undesirable patterns of that same length. I agree with Mat that you should list them explicitly.

If you are in control over these domain(s), can't you have the alternative endpoints redirect to one single host that you can explicitly match against? So that www.foo.co.uk/path would return a HTTP 301, redirecting you to www.foo.com, which would match your filter?

Comment: Thanks, JHH, that's a good solution. Listing all the possible domain extensions is not ideal because we don't want to revisit this work. Redirection to foo.com is the way forward.